# Free a pointer local to a function and return the pointer

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, local, free

I have a C code similar to this. How can I free the pointer and return it ? If I create another local pointer variable and assign `p` to that local pointer variable, it is showing a warning that local variable pointer cannot be returned. **Note that I have a recursion so I want to free up the pointer in the  function itself.** Any workaround. Thanks in advance.

```
char * ABCfunction(){
    char * p = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    //do something with p
    ABCfunction();
    return p;
    //free(p); //Want to do both.
}
```

**UPDATE: Yes, I know that it makes no sense and we cannot do both. I am asking for an alternative approach. The problem is if I don't free the pointer, it is consuming a lot of memory for high input values. I want to get rid of high memory usage.**

Comment: You can't. If you want to return the pointer you can't free the memory it points to, it's that simple.

Comment: It makes no sense to do both.  If you free `p`, the value you return will be invalid and useless.  You free the memory only once, when you're done with it, even if that happens in a different function via a different pointer variable.

Comment: Yes, I know that it makes no sense and we cannot do both. I am asking for an alternative approach. The problem is if I don't free the pointer, it is consuming a lot of memory for high input values. I want to get rid of high memory usage.

Comment: AFAI see this you're not doing anything with `p` which is related to the recursive call. I think you should be calling `ABCfunction()` first and then allocate `p`, do something with it and then return the pointer. Once you're done with the value returned by `ABCfunction` you should be freeing it in your calling function.

Comment: @zapstar It is not the exact code. It is a just a similar code and I am doing something with the return value of `p`.

Comment: @bharadwaj Please give us a better example. The one you've given is not representative of what you're doing and is confusing folks around here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Want to do both.

That is not a good goal.

If you free the pointer, you should not return the pointer. Otherwise, the calling function will get a dangling pointer.

> Note that I have a recursion so I want to free up the pointer in the function itself.

Make sure you capture the returned pointer, use it, and then free it.

Here's what your function should look like:

```
char * ABCfunction()
{
   char * p = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
   //do something with p

   char* p1 = ABCfunction();
   // Use p1.
   // Then free p1
   free(p1);

   return p;
}
```

Comment: Can I use the statement `free(p)` outside the function after using it ? `p` is a local variable.

Comment: @bharadwaj, yes. `p` is a local variable but its value can be returned and used in the calling function.

Comment: Okay. What happens to the other recursive functions' return value called by `ABCfunction()`. Are they already freed up ?

Comment: @bharadwaj, the way you have with your posted code, the value returned from the recursive calls is not captured. As a consequence, you have memory leaks. No, they are not freed up.